# Implementing / enforcing wraparound arithmetic in C

Tags: c, integer-overflow, integer-arithmetic

The C standard says that overflow in arithmetic is undefined.

I would like to know how to implement wraparound arithmetic in a performance-friendly way. This means that overflow checking solutions like presented [here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/INT32-C.+Ensure+that+operations+on+signed+integers+do+not+result+in+overflow) are not an option (as they slow the operation by about an order of magnitude).

I assume the solution would involve writing an assembly routine to do this. Is there a library available that does this (preferably for multiple architecture, although x86 is a must)?

Alternatively, is there a compiler flag (for gcc & clang) that makes the compiler enforce wraparound semantics for integer arithmetic?

Comment: "The C standard says that overflow in arithmetic is undefined." - That's very wrong!

Comment: Use `unsigned` integers where overflow is always defined or compile with `-fwrapv` to get reliable wrap-around overflow on signed integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Signed* overflow is undefined. Unsigned overflow wraps. Implementing signed wraparound arithmetic is mostly a matter of doing everything in unsigned math. There are a few things to be careful about, though:

1. `unsigned short` and `unsigned char` arithmetic works by converting the operands to either `int` or `unsigned int` first. Usually `int`, unless you're on a weird setup where `int` doesn't have enough range to store all `unsigned short` values. That means that converting `short` or `char` to `unsigned short` or `unsigned char` for arithmetic can still produce signed integer overflow and UB. You need to do your math in `unsigned int` or larger to avoid this.
2. unsigned->signed conversion is technically implementation-defined when the original value is beyond the range of the result type. This shouldn't be a problem on most compilers and architectures.

Alternatively, if you want to go the compiler flag route, `-fwrapv` makes signed overflow wrap for addition, subtraction, and multiplication on GCC and Clang. It doesn't do anything about `INT_MIN / -1`, though.